# Can we use adverbs of frequency with "will"?

Tags: grammar, tenses, adverbs, present-tense, future

I’ve seen this text in which "sometimes" has been used with "will". I assume the sentence is explaining a habit, and I wonder why it’s been said with "will".

> Sometimes I'll wave to him in the morning and he doesn't even wave back.

I’ll really appreciate it if you can explain the reason.

Here I add the whole text:

"*The man who lives next to me is moving. I can't say that I'm too upset about it. He's lived next to me for almost five years, but I don't think he's spoken to me more than three or four times. Sometimes I'll wave-to him in the morning and he doesn't even wave back.*"

Comment: Please never post pictures of text. They create accessibility problems because screen readers cannot read them. They cannot be searched, saved, or quoted as text. Please edit this post to replace it with the actual text.

Comment: Yes, _will_ is often used to refer to a habitual action or experience. "Sometimes I will walk in the park in my lunch break."  "We will occasionally go there for a picnic."

Comment: The cited usage is the "Future as Present Tense" version of *[Sometimes] I **would** [do something]*, used to express ***habitual*** actions in the past. It's *slightly* "literary, poetic" compared to the default plain *Present* tense, but people sometimes use the future tense version in such contexts precisely because it more strongly alludes to a habitual action. Which arguably makes it *slightly* less likely when modified by ***sometimes*** (but maybe *more* likely in conjunction with, say, ***often***).

Comment: `Sometimes I will/ I will sometimes` is a common usage ,  google search  for exact phrase  provides millions of hits - https://www.google.com/search?q=%22i+will+sometimes%22 . One question related to the sentence you have cited though, would be - what should it use instead of *doesn't*?  *won't* would agree with *will*. As in - `Sometimes I'll wave to him in the morning and he won't even wave back` . Or probably it can also be *wouldn't*, I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, you will quite often see this usage. Well, reasonably frequently.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/112450/will-for-habitual-action

Comment: Promise to you: I will never say never unless required to do so. They will always do the work when I ask them. The cat will sometimes bring in a dead mouse. Adverbs of frequency are not restricted by verb tenses or forms.

Comment: I don't think "sometimes" is specifically modifying "will" in the sentence, but maybe someone knows different.